# JS инициализация скрипта

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт начинал свою работу только в том случае, если пользователь докрутил до конкретного места на странице? В мое случае, easyPieChart

Comment: нужно подписаться на обработчик прокрутки и каждый раз проверить не находишься ли ты на конкретном месте на странице

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(window).on('scroll.a', function() {
var a = $('#a').position().top-$(window).height()
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=a){
        console.log('aaaaaa')
        $(window).off('scroll.a');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div><div id="a">m</div></div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div >a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div>
```